# FILE * can say if the file is empty?

Tags: c, file

In C, how do I know from FILE* whether that file is empty or not?

Comment: You don't. a FILE* is not necessarily a real file on the disk. Is your keyboard empty? :)

Comment: Is this homework? Or a real problem you're having to solve in the real world? (Homework is *fine*, but you should say.)

Comment: pmg and T.J: this is a real world problem and I think someone knows the answer. Thanks for your valuable comments :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`fseek` to the end, then check if `ftell` returns 0.

Answer (score 5):

Like this:

```
bool isEmpty(FILE *file)
{
    long savedOffset = ftell(file);
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);

    if (ftell(file) == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }

    fseek(file, savedOffset, SEEK_SET);
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're coding for a POSIX system:

```
struct stat sb;
if( fstat(fileno(file), &sb) ) { /* error */ }
if( sb.st_size == 0 ) { /* file is empty */ }
```